# Exotic isomorphism of matrix rings (2)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices

Let $R,S,T$ be (associative, with a 1) rings, and $m,n,r,s$ be non-negative integers.

If

(a)  $R$ is isomorphic to $M_{m\times m}(T)$ and $S$ is isomorphic to $M_{n\times n}(T)$ and $m\cdot r = n\cdot s$

or
(b)  $R$ and $S$ both have exactly one element

then $M_{r\times r}(R)$ is isomorphic to $M_{s\times s}(S)$.

Based on the last comment on Tom Goodwillie's answer to [my earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38385/exotic-isomorphism-of-matrix-rings), (a) and (b) apparently do not exhaust the cases in which $M_{r\times r}(R)$ is isomorphic to $M_{s\times s}(S)$.

What are examples to show that?  Can they be finite?

Is there a relatively simple exhaustion of when $M_{r\times r}(R)$ is isomorphic to $M_{s\times s}(S)$ in terms of $R,S,r,s$?  What if $R$ and $S$ are assumed to be finite?

Comment: You can take $R$ to be the column finite, row finite matrices. Then all of its matrix rings are isomorphic to it.

Comment: Off-topic, but since your profile has no contact details: you may or may not want to respond to remarks following your comment at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52032/

Comment: Thanks, I just did.  (I'd completely forgotten about that question.)